# Saving Numeric Matrix and Cell Data to CSV File in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, matlab-guide

in Matlab I have one 100X4000 mat which contains doubles and I have a 100X1 cell of chars. now the problem is how can I write all together in a CSV file. Matlab doesn't let me to do that. a shorter example is like this: first mat

```
0   1   2
0   0   0
0   5   3
9   0   7
0   4   0
```

second cell:

```
apple
banana
cherry
peach
other
```

the expected result (A) is:

```
0   1   2 apple
0   0   0 banana
0   5   3 cherry
9   0   7 peach
0   4   0 other
```

final goal is to do this:

```
csvwrite('dataLabels.csv',A);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551153/writing-a-cell-matlab-to-a-csv-file

Comment: @brodroll That answer is very inefficient. Also that's only half the question. This one has a numeric matrix too.

Comment: OP can you verify if [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29837234/802378) works for you and kindly accept if it's incorrect

Comment: @krisdestruction The one in the link provided requires writing numeric and char data to a csv, so they are the same in this aspect. The only difference is that here the data is in two different "containers" instead of a single cell array.

Comment: Yes so the problem exists from the OP's question of how to convert it to a numeric. The answer in the linked post is still pretty inefficient IMHO.

Comment: @user667222 Can you kindly confirm if my solution is the one you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The code is as simple as follows:

```
% Toy Example Data
B = [0 1 2; 0 0 0; 0 5 3; 9 0 7; 0 4 0];
C = { 'apple' 'banana' 'cherry' 'peach' 'other' }';

B = num2str(B,'%i   %i   %i');
dlmwrite( 'dataLabels.csv', [B repmat( char(' '), length(C), 1 ) char( C{:} )], '' );
```

So what you want to do is change your matrix `B` into a char with your desired spacing. That's what the `num2str` function does with those parameters. Then you can use `dlmwrite` to delimit with no spacing. The code `char( C{:} )` simply converts the cell into a char.

The code `repmat( char(' '), length(C), 1 )` is just to put a space in between the matrix `B` and char cell `C`.
Results

```
0   1   2 apple 
0   0   0 banana
0   5   3 cherry
9   0   7 peach 
0   4   0 other
```

Comment: You made me curious about how much more efficient this solution is! But I can already tell this is indeed more efficient since you eliminated the need of 2 for loops. Nice one +1

Comment: Thank you :) The solution you linked did indeed work for both numerics and cells, but as you can see, everyone resorts to the double loop and this is a very vectorized solution. I hate clunky code XD

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fopen(filepath, w)` and `fprintf(fileId, data)` to write several matrices as strings in a csv file.

Example:

```
function createCSV(name, data1, data2)
fileId = fopen(path/to/file.csv, 'w');
[x, y] = size(data);

for i = 1:x
    for j = 1:y
        fprintf(fileId, num2str(data(x, y)));
        fprintf(fileId, ',');
    end
    fprintf(fileId, num2str(data2(x)));
    fprintf(fileId, '\n');
end

end
```

### [fopen](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), [fprintf](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html)

Comment: Your code is very inefficient due to the double loop :/